# Computing using functions and arrays / Output error: Not a Number

Tags: javascript, arrays

Background: I'm practicing arrays and functions and am having trouble computing the sum of array items. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the function I'm writing but I'm not sure what. Using 8 input fields I'm pulling data into a array one item at a time and converted to floating numbers(for now...I'll try to fix that later). I've created a function that will compute the total of this list but it only outputs NaN.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

```js
function myfunction() {
  list = [];
  list[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number1').value);
  list[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number2').value);
  list[2] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number3').value);
  list[3] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number4').value);
  list[4] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number5').value);
  list[5] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number6').value);
  list[6] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number7').value);
  list[7] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('number8').value);

  function total(myvals) {
    let total = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i <= myvals.length; i++) {
      total += myvals[i];
    }
    return total;
  }

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = total(list);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="number1" id="number1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number2" id="number2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number3" id="number3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number4" id="number4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number5" id="number5"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number6" id="number6"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number7" id="number7"><br>
  <input type="text" name="number8" id="number8"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Compute Score" onclick="javascript:myfunction()">
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Not exactly your problem but to prevent the form from submitting, try `<input type="button">` instead (or even better `<button type="button">`)

Comment: Don't use `<=` in your loop comparison condition use just `<`. With `<=` your last iteration is going to make your `i` be `8` which you have no array element for, ie `myvals[8]` is `undefined`. So `total += undefined` gets you a `NaN`

Comment: And to avoid off by one errors completely, use array.reduce: `list.reduce((acc, val) => acc+val)`

Comment: Why not use input type=number?

Comment: @PatrickEvans This definitely helped. Once I changed  <= to < this resolved my problem. I'm now able to calculate the sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using a for loop with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Additionally, I cleaned up your code a bit. Run the snippet below:

**EDIT**: Included some comments to show what's happening.

```js
function myfunction() {
  let total = 0;

  //get the value for each element being called by querySelectorAll
  //add values to total to get a sum
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => total += +el.value);

  //append the new value to the results div
  document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="number1" id="number1"><br>
<input type="text" name="number2" id="number2"><br>
<input type="text" name="number3" id="number3"><br>
<input type="text" name="number4" id="number4"><br>
<input type="text" name="number5" id="number5"><br>
<input type="text" name="number6" id="number6"><br>
<input type="text" name="number7" id="number7"><br>
<input type="text" name="number8" id="number8"><br>

</form>

<br/><br/>

<button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Compute Score</button>

<br/><br/>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - in HTML forms and their elements use names.
2 - each element of a form can be accessed by name with the form as parent
3 - if several elements have the same name (with the same type of preference) then they form an object collection

PS: I have used here [... myForm.numX] to transform the myForm.numX collection to array, so that it can accept the arry.map () method
this way:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']
  ,   res    = document.getElementById('results')
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = evt =>
  {
  evt.preventDefault()  // disable submit
  
  let list = [...myForm.numX].map(inp => parseFloat(inp.value))
    
  res.textContent = list.reduce((t,v)=>t+v,0)
  
  // control...
  console.clear()
  console.log( myForm.numX.length, JSON.stringify(list)  )
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 2"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 3"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 4"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 5"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 6"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 7"><br>
  <input type="text" name="numX" placeholder="num 8"><br>

  <button type="submit">Compute Score</button>
</form>

<div id="results">..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I was able to fix my source code by removing
"<=" in the for loop and adding "<" in its place. Thanks everyone, I will look over everything else for extra practice!